# mocking CanCan authorization while testing controllers with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, cancan

Here is the Controller I want to test:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  #other actions here

end
```

As you can see I use CanCan method `load_and_authorize_resource` so I've written a ControllerHelper for RSpec:

```
# spec/support/controller_spec.rb
module ControllerHelper
  def should_authorize(action, subject)
    controller.should_receive(:authorize!).with(action, subject).and_return('passed!')
  end
end
```

Then I've written the UserController Spec:

```
# spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  describe "GET #index" do
    before do
      @user = mock_model(User)
      should_authorize(:index, @user)
      User.stub!(:find).and_return(@user)
    end

    context "if the user passes all the authorizations" do
      it "populates an array of users" do
        User.should_receive(:find).and_return(@user)
        get :index
      end
      it "renders the :index view" do
        get :index
        response.should render_template :index
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but I get this error

```
Failures:

1) UsersController GET #index if the user passes all the authorizations populates an array of users
       Failure/Error: get :index
         #<UsersController:0x000000037ee750> received :authorize! with unexpected arguments
            expected: (:index, #<User:0x1bf597c @name="User_1001">)
            got: (:index, User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, phone: string, address: string, city: string, cap: string, partitaiva: string, ragionesociale: string))
         # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) UsersController GET #index if the user passes all the authorizations renders the :index view
       Failure/Error: get :index
         #<UsersController:0x00000003802f98> received :authorize! with unexpected arguments
            expected: (:index, #<User:0x1bb0048 @name="User_1002">)
            got: (:index, User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, phone: string, address: string, city: string, cap: string, partitaiva: string, ragionesociale: string))
         # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:19:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

EDIT

now my spec is like that, and it works!

```
# spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do

  describe "GET #index" do
    before do
      @user = mock_model(User)
      should_authorize(:index, User)
      User.stub!(:all).and_return(@user)
    end

    context "if the user passes all the authorizations" do
      it "populates an array of users" do
        User.should_receive(:all).and_return(@user)
        get :index
      end
      it "renders the :index view" do
        get :index
        response.should render_template :index
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Thanks,

enrico

Comment: I wouldn't test if authorize is called. That's on CanCan and it should be tested see https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/spec/cancan/controller_additions_spec.rb

Comment: See this section in the cancan wiki: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Testing-Abilities#controller-testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using load_and_authorize_resource in cancan, it only passes an instance of user to the authorize method when the action is `update`, `show`, `edit` or `destroy`(I think). 
When the action is `index` it passes the User class instead.

That's why your expectation inside `should_authorize` fails

You can see how cancan does the loading here:

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/controller_resource.rb#L76