# NoMethodError for Rspec controller test in Rails 4 engine using CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, cancan, rails-engines

I'm trying to write some controller tests for my engine, but every time I hit a controller that uses a cancan method for authorization (load_and_authorize_resource, authorize, etc) the tests fail with a NoMethodError:

> undefined method 'load_and_authorize_resource' for Myquiz::MoodleQuizzesController:Class (NoMethodError)

I get the same error if I switch out the CanCan method with anything else such as authorize.

Here is the relevant part of my controller:

```
module Myquiz
  class MoodleQuizzesController < Myquiz::ApplicationController
    load_and_authorize_resource :except => [:landing_page, :latest_quizzes]
    ...
```

Here is the ApplicationController:

```
module Myquiz
  class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    layout "myquiz/myquiz_layout"

    def current_ability
      @current_ability ||= Myquiz::Ability.new(current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

The abilities file:

```
module Myquiz
  class Ability
    include CanCan::Ability

    def initialize(user)
      user ||= Myquiz.user_class.new

      if user.has_role? :myquiz_admin || user.is_admin?
        can :manage, :all
      elsif user.has_role? :instructor
        can :read, :all
      elsif user.has_role? :student
        can :read, :landing_page
      else
        cannot :manage, :all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I've been playing around with the spec file using tips from various sources on the web and StackOverflow, trying to get it to work but I have not had any success. It does not even seem to be getting into the before statements in the spec before erroring; however it does set the user, series, and quiz.

```
require "spec_helper"

module Myquiz
  describe MoodleQuizzesController do
    routes { Myquiz::Engine.routes }

    let!(:user)   { create(:user, :admin) }
    let!(:series) { create(:series) }
    let!(:quiz)   { create(:moodle_quiz, series_id: series.id) }

    before{ controller.stub(:authenticate_user!).and_return true }
    before{ controller.stub(:current_user).and_return user }
    before(:each) do
      @ability = Object.new
      @ability.extend(CanCan::Ability)
      controller.stub(:current_ability).and_return @ability
    end
    ...
  end
end
```

The controllers work in the app when I'm clicking around, and the specs will run if I comment out the CanCan authentication method. It's only in the test environment that I seem to be having problems.

Comment: This stackoverflow question should help... it talks about how to stub out the CanCan `load_and_manage_resources` for controller tests... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750232/mocking-cancan-authorization-while-testing-controllers-with-rspec

Comment: Thank you for the link, I looked it over and tried the should_authorize support method, but I am still getting the same error. The execution does not even seem to be hitting the before blocks before the error appears.